# Inline SVG with Link

Tags: html, svg

I was wondering how I can embed an SVG directly into HTML (not via src) and use the image as an link with the  tag?
When I put an  tag around the  the SVG disappears suddenly.
Thought that would be absolutely no problem, but could not find anything with Google. Or in general: what is the most recommended way to work with SVGs?

Thanks so much for helping!

Comment: Can you put your code snippet in the question, as I don't see why wrapping the SVG would be a problem? There are multiple ways of dealing with it, depending also on whether you want specific parts of the image to point to different links.

Comment: Well, my bad! I don't know what I did wrong because now everything is working fine. Just put an < a > tag around the < svg >. Sorry and thanks.